# Wordpress - 'strpos() empty needle' and 'cannot modify header' warnings

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

Months ago, I have placed a 301 redirect rule in my `.htaccess` file to redirect all the `www` request to a `non-www` request.

The problem is two days ago, when I tried to access my `example.net` site using `www.example.net` I get the following warnings in the page and website is not loaded.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXBMF.png

Here are the corresponding lines:

**1. Plugin.php** Line 647 = `if ( strpos( $file, $realdir ) === 0 ){`

Full function:

```
/**
 * Gets the basename of a plugin.
 *
 * This method extracts the name of a plugin from its filename.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $file The filename of plugin.
 * @return string The name of a plugin.
 */
function plugin_basename( $file ) {
    global $wp_plugin_paths;

    foreach ( $wp_plugin_paths as $dir => $realdir ) {
        if ( strpos( $file, $realdir ) === 0 ) { /** LINE 646 */
            $file = $dir . substr( $file, strlen( $realdir ) );
        }
    }

    $file = wp_normalize_path( $file );
    $plugin_dir = wp_normalize_path( WP_PLUGIN_DIR );
    $mu_plugin_dir = wp_normalize_path( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR );

    $file = preg_replace('#^' . preg_quote($plugin_dir, '#') . '/|^' . preg_quote($mu_plugin_dir, '#') . '/#','',$file); // get relative path from plugins dir
    $file = trim($file, '/');
    return $file;
}
```

**2. Pluggable.php** Line 1178 = `header("Location: $location", true, $status);`

Full file: http://pastebin.com/0zMJZxV0

I use WordPress only to write some articles. My PHP knowledge is very basic and limited only to locate errors.

Please help me figure out the problem with this. As I have read from the Codex FAQ, they say that empty strings may be a culprit for the `pluggable.php` error. But I have no idea how to locate it and I have attached the file for your reference.

Please provide your suggestions to avoid this error in the future. Thanks in advance.

**3. EDIT - `wp setting` file:** (the error line - `include_once( $plugin );` )

```
// Load active plugins.
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() as $plugin ) {
    wp_register_plugin_realpath( $plugin );
    include_once( $plugin );
}
unset( $plugin );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: I have tried finding that BOM issue. But my files are in perfect shape.

Comment: You're not understanding...that's the ONLY thing it could be. Look in plugins as well.

Comment: I looked at all the PHP files in my plugin folder. There are no empty spaces before are after the PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the header information has been discussed in here: [Cannot modify header information error in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551689/cannot-modify-header-information-error-in-wordpress?rq=1). Could you give this a try and see whether this solves this part of your problem?.

On the other issue:
try `var_dump ($file)` (for instance -- or echo $file ) to see what they actually contain.

Comment: Where should I type this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration path of plugins :

```
var_dump($wp_plugin_paths);
```

You've got an error because $realdir is empty.

Comment: Um...Where should I type this?

Comment: Check  wp-settings.php